# My PC keeps crashing from a bugcheck

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, bsod, minidumps

My PC keeps changing from a bug check and I am clueless as to what caused it. And I am not sure of how to use DBG.

I have attached a minidump to this post. Hopefully some kindhearted soul would be 
able to me decipher this.

https://www.transferbigfiles.com/download/file/3391915a-633b-4205-96dc-bf7e950dd60f?rt=jrviCXVvA26w8CQAcewY_g2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get a memory corruption (1 Bit) in the file win32k.sys. This causes the crash:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION (3b)
An exception happened while executing a system service routine.
Arguments:
Arg1: 00000000c000001d, Exception code that caused the bugcheck
Arg2: fffff96000260b94, Address of the instruction which caused the bugcheck
Arg3: ffffd00022fde440, Address of the context record for the exception that caused the bugcheck
Arg4: 0000000000000000, zero.

Debugging Details:
------------------


DUMP_FILE_ATTRIBUTES: 0x8
  Kernel Generated Triage Dump

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc000001d - {AUSNAHME}  Ung ltige Anweisung  Es wurde versucht, eine ung ltige Anweisung auszuf hren.

FAULTING_IP: 
win32k!vExpandAndCopyText+534
fffff960`00260b94 1e              ???

CONTEXT:  ffffd00022fde440 -- (.cxr 0xffffd00022fde440;r)
rax=ffffd00022fdefa0 rbx=0000000000000001 rcx=ffffd00022fdeff6
rdx=00000000fffffffd rsi=ffffd00022fdf95c rdi=fffff901447e9b60
rip=fffff96000260b94 rsp=ffffd00022fdee70 rbp=ffffd00022fdf3b0
 r8=fffff90144055010  r9=0000000000000001 r10=fffff901447e9b60
r11=000000000000000a r12=0000000000000000 r13=ffffd00022fdfcc8
r14=000000000000000a r15=fffff901447e9b60
iopl=0         nv up ei ng nz ac po nc
cs=0010  ss=0018  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00210296
win32k!vExpandAndCopyText+0x534:
fffff960`00260b94 1e              ???
Last set context:
rax=ffffd00022fdefa0 rbx=0000000000000001 rcx=ffffd00022fdeff6
rdx=00000000fffffffd rsi=ffffd00022fdf95c rdi=fffff901447e9b60
rip=fffff96000260b94 rsp=ffffd00022fdee70 rbp=ffffd00022fdf3b0
 r8=fffff90144055010  r9=0000000000000001 r10=fffff901447e9b60
r11=000000000000000a r12=0000000000000000 r13=ffffd00022fdfcc8
r14=000000000000000a r15=fffff901447e9b60
iopl=0         nv up ei ng nz ac po nc
cs=0010  ss=0018  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00210296
win32k!vExpandAndCopyText+0x534:
fffff960`00260b94 1e              ???
Resetting default scope

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  CODE_CORRUPTION

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x3B

PROCESS_NAME:  firefox.exe

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 6.3.9600.17298 (debuggers(dbg).141024-1500) amd64fre

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff9600026011f to fffff96000260b94

STACK_TEXT:  
nt!KeBugCheckEx
nt!KiBugCheckDispatch
nt!KiSystemServiceHandler
nt!RtlpExecuteHandlerForException
nt!RtlDispatchException
nt!KiDispatchException
nt!KiExceptionDispatch
nt!KiInvalidOpcodeFault
win32k!vExpandAndCopyText
win32k!EngTextOut
win32k!GreExtTextOutWLocked
win32k!GreExtTextOutWInternal
win32k!NtGdiExtTextOutW
nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd



CHKIMG_EXTENSION: !chkimg -lo 50 -d !win32k
    fffff96000260b8e - win32k!vExpandAndCopyText+52e
    [ b9:b1 ]
1 error : !win32k (fffff96000260b8e)

MODULE_NAME: memory_corruption

IMAGE_NAME:  memory_corruption

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  memory_corruption

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  0

MEMORY_CORRUPTOR:  ONE_BIT

STACK_COMMAND:  .cxr 0xffffd00022fde440 ; kb

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  MEMORY_CORRUPTION_ONE_BIT

BUCKET_ID:  MEMORY_CORRUPTION_ONE_BIT
```

First, check your RAM for errors (with memtest86+ or a different tool). If this is fine, run `chkdsk C: /f` to detect HDD issues and if this is fine, run `sfc /scannow` to detect damaged files. If sfc can't fix damages, run [DISM](http://blogs.technet.com/b/joscon/archive/2012/09/26/fixing-component-store-corruption-in-windows-8-and-windows-server-2012.aspx) to fix them:

```
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
```

If all is fine, your G Skill Intl F3-1600C9-8GXM RAM may not be compatible with your ASUS H97-PRO GAMER motherboard or the RAM timings are bad.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will try this and see if it works. I made some changes on BIOS and did not get any crashes recently.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced one of piece of RAM and there were no more issues since.

Thanks for the replies :)